# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'category_posts' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, html, django

im currently working on website, which can show posts written by people. For this posts i have a database. On the main i need to show all the posts which i have in database. There should be some link which will go to page with posts information. I have trouble with all pages - there is error `NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'category_posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']`. When i open my website locally it shows that the error in `<a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'blog:category_posts' post.category.slug %}">`

There is the code:
views.py

```
def category_posts(request, category_slug):
    template = 'blog/category.html'
    posts = Post.objects.select_related(
        'author',
        'category',
        'location',
        ).filter(
        category__slug=category_slug,
        is_published=True,
        pub_date__lte=now())
    category = get_object_or_404(
        Category.objects.select_related('title', 'description', 'slug')
        .filter(is_published=True),
        slug=category_slug
        )
    context = {'posts': posts,
               'category': category}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

urls.py

```
from blog import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'blog'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_posts,
         name='category_posts'),
]
```

category_link.html

```
<a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'blog:category_posts' post.category.slug %}">
  «{{ post.category.title }}»
</a>
```

Comment: `.select_related('title', 'description', 'slug')` seems quite strange... As for the the `category_link` it either means you have not `{% for post in posts %}` or, the `slug` of the related `Category` is empty...

Comment: I have models, so I’m trying to get title, description and slug from another model by using this method. It’s still wrong?

Comment: @Ari: wrong, no, but a bit odd...